# MP3 files cut off in the Ubuntu One Android app

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I noticed today on my phone (Droid X running Android 2.2.1) that when streaming the Ubuntu One app would skip to the next song before the previous one had finished.

Looking into it, one of the mp3s downloaded from the server was only 2.5MB instead of 4.2MB as it shows on the server itself via one.ubuntu.com.

It's happened with multiple tracks today (I remember it happening once the first time I used the app too but shrugged it off as a glitch).

The app itself shows a star on the playlist item indicating the file was downloaded even though it was apparently cut off for some reason, perhaps lack of good cell coverage, or some sort of dropped connection. It seems like the latter may be happening and instead of showing an error or retrying it just stops and shows the download is complete.

Comment: There was a server upgrade -- https://twitter.com/UbuntuOne/status/19827011518210048

Comment: It's still happening. Only 3 out of the 12 tracks in my queue were not cut off on the ride home today. This is after I deleted the subsonic folder on my sdcard to clear the cache and make sure things redownloaded. I also don't understand why there isn't some sort of redundancy check in the app, so even if the server is down it will do something like retry or show me an error instead of saying the download was successful and leaving me with a corrupt file.

Answer (score 2):

We are aware of the issue, and will fix it as soon as possible. You can [subscribe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) to the [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+bug/655788) to stay up to date with the progress we make on this.