# Upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

I'm new to these forums so I'll be quick.

When I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 from 10.04 I get this error, I have tried upgrading from Terminal and Update Manager as well.

> Could not determine the upgrade 
>   An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade: 
>   E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be 
>   caused by held packages. 
>   This can be caused by: 
>   * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
>  
>   * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
>   If none of this applies, then please report this bug against the 
>   'update-manager' package and include the files in 
>   /var/log/dist-upgrade/ in the bug report. 
>   Restoring original system state 
>   Thanks 
>   Aborting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Bug #606652](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/606652).

Possible Workaround:

- Uninstall `xserver-xorg-video-all` (and `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`).
- Upgrade.
- Install `xserver-xorg-video-all` (and `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`).

You can [subscribe to a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) and follow its progress.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu since version 6.x, and every time I wanted to do an upgrade, I experienced problems and issues, mostly related to packages and sometime related to hardware. And every time, I finally found that it would have been easier to simply reinstall Ubuntu, despite the fact that I then have to reinstall my applications. But I see several advantages to this:

1. You have to backup all your data to another device, since a full install also means erasing your hard disk, unless you planned id and had your data in another partition. Having a backup is always a good idea, and never hurts.
2. You only have the applications that you need, no more "left-overs" of other applications you installed. It is easy to install all kinds of programs as you find them. but do you remove them once you're done ?
3. Given all possible programs and utilities that are installed, and may not be ready for the new version of the distro, an upgrade to a new version is unlikely to upgrade those packages. Incompatibilities, missing libraries, etc... that can happen so easily.....
4. It also gives you a chance to cleanup your files, and if you re-do the file system you eliminate all fragmentation issues that can happen in any file system, under any OS.

Yes, more work, but also a better system at the end. And this is also true of other OSes. However with Linux, the $$$ cost is the same, whether this is an upgrade or a full reinstall: ZERO. Other OSes will charge you different prices depending on whether this is an upgrade or a full install.