# Will we be able to change the launcher icons?

Tags: unity, customization

For example, if i use faenza icon set, will the launcher icons change to faenza?

Comment: I believe this bug addresses your question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/663524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they will (probably). The Launcher items just use the associated .desktop file, in which the icon is *usually* specified as a name referring to an Icon in the current set, unity should use this information.

[image]

As theprise points out, this doesn't work [at the minute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do), so you may want to [follow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) [**this bug report**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/663524).

The status of the bug indicates that this is currently being implemented.