# Does the global application menu support Java applications?

Tags: java, appmenu

I am a heavy user of Java applications such as Matlab and Maple. Will the global menu support these very important packages?

If not, are there plans to do this?

Comment: Offtopic but you should look at these (http://alternativeto.net/software/maple/?profile=online&platform=linux&license=opensource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have global menu integration for **any Java based application** that implements a JMenubar by installing Jayatana:

- Copy this script
- Save it in your Desktop or Home directory .
- Open a terminal, type `cd ~/`
- Type again: `bash path_to_the_newly_saved_script`
- Follow instructions (You need an internet connection).

  #!/bin/bash

  ```
  # ----------------------------------------------
  # Author: hanynowsky@gmail.com
  # Before executing this script make sure 
  # you're in your home directory `cd $HOME`
  #--------------------------------------------------

  # -------------------------------------NOTICE------------
  # APPLICABLE ONLY IN UBUNTU UNITY 
  # This script installs Jayatana for your JDKs 
  # It supposes you already have set your JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc
  # You will be prompted to choose which JDK to set as Default 
  # (choose the corresponding index).
  # In case you already installed jayatana and want to re-install, 
  # please uninstall then install again.
  # ------------------------------------------------------

  # -------------------------------------LICENSE--------------------
  #Licensed under the GNU LGPL, Version 3.0 (the "License");
  # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------

  #JDKPATH=`echo $JAVA_HOME | sed -e 's/bash://g' | sed -e 's/Is a directory//g'`
  #JDKPATH=eval "echo $JAVA_HOME"
  JDKPATH=`echo $JAVA_HOME | grep [^*]`
  USERHOME=`echo $HOME`
  JAYATANADD="http://java-swing-ayatana.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.4/jayatana"

  # INSTALL 
  INSTALLCOM () {
  sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk libunity-dev libxt-dev gcc make ant subversion 
  sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 
  svn checkout $JAYATANADD 
  sudo ant install -buildfile $USERHOME/jayatana/build.xml -v
  sudo ant config -v 
  sudo update-alternatives --config java 
  sudo update-alternatives --config javac
  sudo ant install -Djava.home.7=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 -f $USERHOME/jayatana/build.xml -v -l $USERHOME/Desktop/jayatana-stall.log
  sudo ant config -Djava.home.7=$JDKPATH -f ~/jayatana/build.xml -v -l $USERHOME/Desktop/jayatana-stall.log
  }

  # UNINSTALL
  UNINSTALLCOM (){
  sudo ant deinstall -buildfile $USERHOME/jayatana/build.xml -v
  sudo ant deconfig -buildfile $USERHOME/jayatana/build.xml -v
  sudo ant deconfig -Djava.home.7=$JDKPATH -f $USERHOME/jayatana/build.xml -v -l $USERHOME/Desktop/jayatana-stall.log
  }

  # DELETE Jayatana Folder created by subversion checkout
  UNDIR() {
  read -p "Delete Jayatana Folder too? Enter ( y ) to delete or ( n ) otherwise : " choice
  if [ "$choice" = "y" ]; then mv $HOME/jayatana $HOME/.local/share/Trash/files/
  elif [ "$option" = "n" ]; then echo"Jayatana Folder is kept by $USER";
  echo "you can delete it later : ~/jayatana";
  else echo "Jayatana Folder is kept by $USER , you can delete it later : ~/jayatana";
  fi
  }

  # COMMON
  COMMON() {
  echo "$JDKPATH : is your default JDK. Version: " 
  echo `java -version`
  }
  eval COMMON;
  read -p "Enter ( i ) to install or ( u ) to uninstall : " option
  if [ "$option" = "i" ]; then eval INSTALLCOM
  elif [ "$option" = "u" ]; then eval UNINSTALLCOM;eval UNDIR;
  else echo "Aborted by $USER";
  fi
  exit 0;
  ```

You can see detailed information in this post:
[Ubuntu Global Menu Support for Java Applications](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

---

For **ECLIPSE**, this is different. The package ECLIPSE is blacklisted in the library libappmenu.so because its integration with Global Menu is somehow broken (menus are sometimes dupmlicated and disordered). Same goes for EMACS23 (Dynamic menus do not appear when using global menu). So they're blacklisted, until developers provide a global fix.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thanks! Any idea whether the Ubuntu developers are aware of this?

Comment: Yeah. They are aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/618587).

I recommend subscribing to it to follow its progress. ([How to subscribe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug))

Comment: Great, subscribed to it. Shoud I make a comment about my problem or would it just annoy the developers?

Comment: Click the "Affects me" near the top, this is the equivalent of leaving a comment that it's important to you without sending bug mail to hundreds of people.

Comment: Any news on this Jorge?

Comment: @Ingo it's in the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The opened bug mentioned in this thread is about Eclipse, which doesn't use the default Java GUI toolkit (Swing) used by many Java applications (Eclipse uses SWT).

So, we probably are going to have no Unity integration for Java applications even if they solve that specific bug.

Comment: I have filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/984916 for Swing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called [java-swing-ayatana](https://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/) that supports this. I'm not sure if it works with every java application. But it now has a PPA install so it's pretty easy.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

You may need to restart your session after this.

Answer (score 0):

Any command which can be run from the command line can be added to the menu.

Global menu items can be found in /usr/share/menu.  You should be able to add new entries by editing an existing entry.

Personal entries can be be added by right clicking on the Applications item on the panel.