# Square in calendar on random day

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, calendar

I'm running Unity on Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition here.

In this [screenshot](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/4432/calendarm.png), there is this small orange square on the calendar which I presume is supposed to mark the present day of month.

[image]

Still, it seems to highlight a random date, which can be set by any user.

It is worse: even if I set it to the current day of month, it doesn't get updated when the clock hits 12AM.

So, I would like it to highlight the current day, update itself automatically, and keep normal users from changing it.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, activating NTP didn't solve any of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-datetime/+bug/649800).

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)