# What are the changes between kernel in 10.04 and 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, kernel

Is there a place where I could check what are the differences between kernel in version 10.04 and 10.10 ? 
The reason is that from time to time I have total system freezes with 10.10 on Dell Inspiron 1501 which was no the case on 10.04.

Comment: As the first question states, there's been a **lot** of changes, any of which that maybe the cause of your problems. I suggest you change your question ask for help in debugging this matter. Or you may simply degrade to 10.04 as it is an LTS release after all.

Comment: You can see the change log between the default kernel versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 used Kernel version 2.6.32 with the DRM from 2.6.33<sup>[[src]](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2010-March/009214.html)</sup>. Ubuntu 10.10 used 2.6.35.

The change logs are at  http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/, but they are *big*. The changes in .35 are in [this 6.3MB text file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ChangeLog-2.6.35). You may be better off searching [Bugs in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) to find more about your particular problem. There are [34 results for "Inspiron 1501"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.searchtext=%22Inspiron+1501+%22&orderby=-importance&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=).

Comment: I checked bugs reported in a launchpad and it seems that there exist bug entry quite similar to my problem : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/226784

Comment: @tommyk You can [Subscribe to the bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) in launchpad , to keep up with its status, if you want. Make sure to click "Does this bug affect you?" in the top left.