# Restore rearranging programs on taskbar in classic mode?

Tags: 11.04, taskbar, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I Can't swap the windows on Window List at gnome panel after upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35404/why-i-cant-swap-the-windows-on-window-list-at-gnome-panel-after-upgrading)

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I've enjoyed being able to rearrange the programs on the bottom task bar. Now, in 11.04's "classic" desktop, I don't seem to be able to do that any longer. Is there a way to restore this functionality? Some hidden gconf setting? Or has this been removed from the code entirely?

For example, here I am trying to drag Firefox onto Evolution. In 10.10 and previous, this would have caused the two apps to swap places on the window list.

[image: dragging window buttons]

Comment: aha, found 2 more people with the same problem.