# Is there a way to copy-paste text into Unity's new 'Alt+F2' launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash, clipboard

When I try to copy/paste text, it always comes up with that square with 4 characters inside of it.

Sometimes I don't want to launch something in a terminal (e.g. conky), and not being able to copy/paste into the alt+f2 dialog makes it difficult - especially if I have to type in a long file URI.

I used to use Gnome-Do and Synapse for this but am trying to give Unity a chance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. It is a bug currently affecting 37+ people, see [filed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/736222)

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)