# How to force active Launcher webpages to be from the Chromium icon?

Tags: 11.04, launcher, chromium, shortcuts

So, I'm not quite sure how to word this, but I created some custom launchers for Chromium Browser's application shortcuts:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the Social website one is active because I opened Facebook in a quicklist. However, if I were to now open up a chromium tab or use a Google service, it would only add a triangle indicator to the Social websites icon instead of the respective launchers it was initiated from. Is there a way to force the Application shortcut windows to be indicated by their respective icons, or if not, a way to force Chromium to be the icon with all of the triangles?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/692462) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [actually a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/692462) in the window matching bamf does that we haven't been able to fix yet.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)