# How to make the lock screen look like the login screen?

Tags: gdm, lightdm, lock-screen

Is there any way to make the login screen from a locked session (either by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or from a screen timeout) look like the login screen when you're starting a new session? I hate that everything on the lock screen aside from the password input is black.

Comment: It's worth noting that in 11.10/Oneiric/GNOME3/whatever that the lock screen now uses your desktop background instead of a black screen.

Comment: In Gnome 3 things are a bit more complicated. Lock screen do use desktop background... But how to change it except replacing image files or editing xml's?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## GDM

You can't make the lock screen look like the login screen.

However, you can use a theme for the lock screen. There are quite a few available at [gnome-look.org](http://www.gnome-look.org). Here's an [example](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/elementary+lock+screen?content=107792).

Answer (score 8):

## GDM

The answer may be a little bit late, but aside from setting the theme of the actual **unlock dialog** you can also set the background (i.e. the black space around the dialog) to whatever image you like. Just run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename --type string /usr/share/backgrounds/Holes_by_FireCobold.jpg
```

Replace the last path in the command with the path to the image you desire to use. Do not forget to restart your desktop session (or try to restart `gconfd-2` by killing it, at least).

**EDIT:** unless you configured the background of the login screen (e.g. via Ubuntu Tweak), the above command will also change it.

Comment: I've searched for a solution applicable to Gnome 3. Unfortunately this one isn't.

Answer (score 5):

## LightDM

This was planned 12.04 -here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/878836).  However, it did not make the final release.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Answer (score 2):

If you are somewhat proficient at C and a little bit of GTK, it's possible to have the lock screen **look like** (but not be!) the login screen -- since your main concern seems to be the ugliness of the lock box?

You'd do this by modifying the sources of the `gnome-screensaver` package, which provides the lock screen.

For tips, please see the *How did you figure this out?* section at the end of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/146231/58612). The original question was about repositioning the lock-box to the bottom-left instead of the center. For what you want, you'd move it to the left, make the grey background transparent, and change the sizes of the username and "Password:" text appropriately.

From my experience, the code you need to change is most probably only in two files: `gs-lock-plug.c` and `gs-windows-x11.c`.

If you try this and have any questions, please ask in a comment and I'll try my best to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

## Light DM

This tweak works by replacing call to OnScreen Virtual Keyboard with that of **LightDM**. A better tweak would be to replace the call to **Gnome ScreenSaver Lockscreen**(Ubuntu's default LockScreen till Ubuntu 13.10) with one to **Unity Greeter**(Ubuntu's default Login Screen), but I couldn't find any way to do that.

---

### Method:

Open **Dconf Editor**,select the schema **org.gnome.desktop.screensaver**,edit the variable *embedded-keyboard-command* and replace it's contents with

```
dbus-launch gdmflexiserver -xnest
```

, and then check *embedded-keyboard-enabled* for the same schema.

**Shortcut Commands:**
For the Terminal lovers and lazy ones out there,you can do the above settings with just 2 commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command "dbus-launch gdmflexiserver -xnest"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled true
```

From now onwards, Ubuntu Login Screen (**Unity Greeter**) appears every time the system wake from either Screensaver (**Lock Screen**) or **Suspend**.

---

This method was provided by [alina](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/users/alina) on the Ubuntu Discourse thread [Wake from screensaver directly to the login screen](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/wake-from-screensaver-directly-to-the-login-screen/923). I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** and this method works fine. May work on 12.10,13.04 and 13.10 too.

A limitation with this method is that you'll see the Gnome Screensaver LockScreen for a second before seeing Unity Greeter. Also, as Unity Greeter isn't designed for locking screen, it's not as fast and fluid as the default Lock Screen. **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** will find a solution to these problems by using **Light Locker** instead of **Gnome Screensaver LockScreen**.