# Ubuntu 11.10 Lock Screen

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will there be a new lock screen for 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118087/will-there-be-a-new-lock-screen-for-12-04)

I really like the new login screen that comes with 11.10, and was disappointed that the Lock Screen did not look similar. The current lock screen looks pretty underwhelming in comparison.

I searched this site for a few suggestions on how to make it look a bit better, but they seem to all point to previous versions of Gnome (v2), an example is [How to make the lock screen look like the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42166/how-to-make-lock-screen-look-like-login-screen)

Does anyone know how I can change the theme of the lock screen?

Comment: totally agree, the new login screen is awesome, would like to see ti as the lock screen as well.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice, and it should be displayed on all monitors.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Not a duplicate. I quoted that question in my question, because this question is specifically about 11.10, and the solution in the quoted question does not work, as it is a previous version of Gnome.

Comment: I've added a bounty on the original question so it can be updated. (Though I am pretty sure you can't quite use lightdm like that just yet, but who knows, maybe someone can figure it out)

Comment: @Codemwnci - I'm closing this since this covers the same ground as the linked question - i.e. 11.10 & 12.04 use the same lock-screen.