# Will there be a new lock screen for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

I have [read in many blogs](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-Has-a-New-Lock-Screen-253218.shtml) that old lock screen is replaced by new lock screen in Ubuntu 12.04

But when I installed 12.04 Beta 2 (and updated my system) , its still showing old lock screen. Any idea if its delayed ?

Comment: They took it in despite the regressions (e. g. the leave message feature disappeared).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was [suggested](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836) and I do remember seeing this on my system somewhere down the road in one of the alphas but later updates removed it.

As you can see from comments [`22`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836/comments/22) and [`23`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836/comments/23) this probably wont land on 12.04 since it introduced major regressions that could not easy be fixed on time to test, after all **12.04 is a LTS, we want things to work as good as they can get.**

A far as I can tell, it was really awesome but I do remember having some issues that already described on the bug report. Think you will have to wait for 12.10 to see this implemented properly.

Answer (score -1):

Remove gnome-screen saver and install xscreensaver:

sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver

sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra

Set the option to lock the screen after 1 minute.