# Can I change the lock screen background to be different from the desktop background?

Tags: 11.10, desktop-background, lock-screen

I want the lock screen background to be different from the desktop background in Ubuntu 11.10, how can I do that?

It's okay when I am using 11.04, why 11.10 can't? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could have at the answers here:

[How to make the lock screen look like the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42166/how-to-make-the-lock-screen-look-like-the-login-screen)

And see if any of these are what you want!

Comment: sorry, what if I only want that lock screen background to change?Personally, I think that the lock screen theme is awesome as it shows the avatar of the user...

Comment: The second answer on that page should do it (without changing the Theme), although it seems to change the Log-in screen as well... I hope thats not a problem!