# How to move the lock window on the lock-screen?

Tags: unity, gnome, window-manager, gtk, lock-screen

Is it possible to move the window where you input your password on the lock screen away from the center, e.g. at the lower edge?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### For Unity/Gnome, the position is hard coded and requires patching the `gnome-screensaver` source and rebuilding it

> I don’t expect this to be very difficult

Sorry, but it *is*, because it's hard-coded, at least for Unity and Gnome:

- The lock dialog and lock screen are part of the `gnome-screensaver` package.
- The position of the dialog is controlled via this bit of code at/around line 1212 in `gnome-screensaver/src/gs-window-x11.c`:

  ```
      window->priv->lock_box = gtk_alignment_new (0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
  ```
- The `0.5, 0.5` are the relative X- and Y-dimension center coordinates of the lock dialog (ranging from `0=left/top` to `1=right/bottom`).
- Setting it to e.g. `0.1, 0.9` gives your desired bottom-left alignment. Of course, this requires recompiling from source :(
- Result:

  [image]
  [older widescreen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZXq.jpg)

---

#### The patch

```
--- gnome-screensaver-3.4.1.orig/src/gs-window-x11.c    2012-06-04 18:14:11.000000000 -0700
+++ gnome-screensaver-3.4.1/src/gs-window-x11.c 2012-06-04 18:14:36.972433823 -0700
@@ -1209,7 +1209,7 @@
                     guint32   id)
 {
         window->priv->lock_socket = gtk_socket_new ();
-        window->priv->lock_box = gtk_alignment_new (0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
+        window->priv->lock_box = gtk_alignment_new (0.1, 0.9, 0, 0);
         gtk_widget_show (window->priv->lock_box);
         gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (window->priv->vbox), window->priv->lock_box, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

or see [raw pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pqDYRrW1)

- Customize the `0.1, 0.9` to taste.

---

### To build and install

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-screensaver
mkdir gssrc && cd gssrc
apt-get source gnome-screensaver
wget -Olockbox-left.patch http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pqDYRrW1
patch -i lockbox-left.patch
cd gnome-screensaver-3.4.1
dpkg-source --commit
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i gnome-screensaver_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_{i386|amd64}.deb
cd ..
rm -rf gssrc
killall /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
```

No logout or reboot needed. **To uninstall**, simply do an `apt-get --reinstall install gnome-screensaver`. You'll need to repeat the whole patch-build-install process whenever `gnome-screensaver` is updated, so hold it to make life easier and update when you're ready.

---

### How did you figure this out? (by request)

No, I'm not one of the developers, but I have a decent knowledge of C/C++. Otherwise, it's all Google and heuristics. :)

1. Google tells you there is no obvious way to answer this question.
2. It also tells you the lock dialog is provided by `gnome-screensaver`
3. Download source and examine. Hmm, `gs-lock-plug.c` sounds interesting:

   - ```
     create_page_one (GSLockPlug *plug)
     {
     GtkWidget            *align;
     ...
     align = gtk_alignment_new (0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);
     ```
4. That could be it! Look up `gtk_alignment_new` syntax, change to `0.1, 0.9` and rebuild. Doesn't work :(
5. Notice `debug-screensaver.sh` in source folder, run it, and then lock and login. Output contains:

   - ```
     [find_window_at_pointer] gs-manager.c:668 (19:26:42):    Requesting unlock for screen 0
     [gs_window_request_unlock] gs-window-x11.c:1522 (19:26:42):  Requesting unlock
     [window_dialog_up_changed_cb] gs-manager.c:909 (19:26:42):   Handling window dialog up changed: up
     [handle_window_dialog_up] gs-manager.c:851 (19:26:42):   Handling dialog up
     ```
6. Look at `gs-manager.h`, which includes:

   - `gboolean    gs_manager_request_unlock       (GSManager  *manager);`
7. Examine `gs-manager.c`:

   - ```
     gs_manager_request_unlock (GSManager *manager)
     {
     GSWindow * window;
     ...
     /* Find the GSWindow that contains the pointer */
     window = find_window_at_pointer (manager);
     gs_window_request_unlock (window);
     }
     ```
8. `gs_window_request_unlock` isn't from `gs-manager`. `grep -i -r -n gs_window_request .` reveals:

   - ```
     ./gs-manager.c:1353:        gs_window_request_unlock (window);
     ./gs-window.h:92:void        gs_window_request_unlock     (GSWindow  *window);
     ./test-window.c:66:        gs_window_request_unlock (window);
     ./gs-window-x11.c:1518:gs_window_request_unlock (GSWindow *window)
     ```
9. Heuristically jump to line 1518 in `gs-window-x11.c`; `gs_window_request_unlock` doesn't help directly but contains a number of `window->priv` mentions.
10. Look at `struct GSWindowPrivate` near the beginning of `gs-window-x11.c`. It contains `GtkWidget *lock_box` and `GtkWidget *lock_socket`
11. Search for occurrences of `lock_box` in file; third result is:

    - `window->priv->lock_box = gtk_alignment_new (0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);`
12. Do a little mental victory dance, change, build, test, succeed, post answer, edit answer..and win bounty? :)

Comment: Very good! Haven’t tried it yet, but sounds legit ;-) Could you tell me how you found that out, or are you simply the developer for that?

Comment: See extensive edits :)

Comment: Wow, awesome work! This is by far more extensive than I had even hoped for. Thank you. And yeah, this answer is so deserving of the bounty you got it.