# Change unlock screen appearance

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, lock-screen

I wonder if it's possible to change the appearance of the unlock screen as I'm not a big fan of this default greyish dialog box:

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-E7uZlPKkz6U/T4qGK1bl57I/AAAAAAAABxo/FOTzjtDrRa0/s320/Lock-Screen-Precise.png]
(Image reference: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2012/04/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-review.html)

I have literally no experience with applying any themes in Ubuntu and whenever I've tried to change a specific part of the interface I think I changed pretty much anything but the part I'd like to change.
Therefore I'm also not sure if it's possible to just change this dialog box or if I've to apply a broader theme. Some explanation about the general structure would be very much appreciated.

Also some tips where to find fitting themes and how to apply them would come very handy - or just some links for tutorials explaining this task as I struggle to dig the net for some informational resource :)

Comment: I think this question request an answer more complicated than this answer: [How to move the lock window on the lock-screen?](http://askubuntu.com/a/146231/147044). There is explained how to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's currently no way to configure the appearance of the lock screen.

However, there is [work in progress](http://status.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-quantal/group/topic-quantal-desktop-greeter-lockscreen.html) to improve the appearance of the lock screen by replacing it with the same software that powers the login screen.

Completion of that work is [contingent upon](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-q-system-compositor) development for the [next version of Unity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnityNextSpec) and the [Mir](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir) project, which is planned to drastically revamp the underlying systems behind the login screen, graphical login sessions, user switching, and the lock screen.

A preliminary version of the next version of Unity with an improved lock screen is [scheduled](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1303-unity-ui-iteration-0) to be available for use by developers next month, and the finished product with Mir is [planned](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Spec#Roadmap) to be included in Ubuntu 14.04.