# How can I make lock screen be like the login screen?

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, login-screen, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the lock screen look like the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42166/how-to-make-the-lock-screen-look-like-the-login-screen)

Is it possible to have the login screen displayed when locked instead of that ugly and horrible current lock display , which is the square box in the middle of the screen. Apparently Ubuntu 12.10 may have this feature, This has given me some hope that maybe their is a package already made or even a script that can achieve this.