# Where do I set the lockscreen image path in Trusty?

Tags: lock-screen

I don't want my desktop session wallpaper to be used as lockscreen background.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a per user setting : launch dconf-editor then untick com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds.

For a system wide setting the way is the same as for disabling greeter to use wallpapers and setting a common one from /usr/share/backgrounds:

Set a background with Ubuntu-tweak or

```
sudo -i
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '/usr/share/backgrounds/MyTrusty.jpg'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
```

Comment: I also found a page here http://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper-in-ubuntu-13-04/334992#334992 were they use a slightly difference in commands: they add xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm just after issuing sudo -i

Comment: I found that I received an error unless I manually started `dbus` after changing to the `lightdm` user. I did this by running `eval $(dbus-launch)` before the first `gsettings` call

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Login Screen you can change it for example with help of Ubuntu-Tweak.

1. Install:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
   ```
2. Open Ubuntu-Tweak from Dash
3. Navigate to **Tweaks** > **Login Settings**
4. Click **unlock** and enter your `sudo` password
5. Set desired background image

For more look [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-customize-gdm-36-login-lock.html)

Comment: Not at all: as I said, I meant lockscreen. I already set the login screen background with ubuntu-tweak and I'd like to set the same picture for the locked screen. In dconf I tried to set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.picture-uri to /usr/share/backgrounds/Trusty.jpg but this doesn't work (I didn't reboot yet).

Comment: please check my edited answer.

Comment: also read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42166/how-to-make-the-lock-screen-look-like-the-login-screen

Comment: Thank you Johnny, light locker seems to be the way to do it. It is not installed in my Trusty, maybe because I upgraded 1304->1310->1404. I will now dig further to find if this package is the new default for Ubuntu desktop. bye-bye

Comment: it's available for trusty http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=light+locker&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

Comment: Unfortunately light-locker won't trigger with a custom shortcut "light-locker-command -l" = Super+L when it does from command line or when the set lap time is elapsed. I understood now that Unity has it's own locker that is the default in Trusty. I have to find for a setting to prevent Unity locker to use users' wallpapers and set it to use the Unity greeter backgound I set with ubuntu-tweak or a third picture. Thank you