# Notification appears on 'wrong' screen

Tags: notification, notify-osd

Work provides me with four large screens, which in Xinerama leads to a nice 5120 x 3200 pixel display (running Ubuntu classic, no animations).

All very nice indeed --- but the 'notifications' appear in the top right of the xinerama screen (display three out of four) when I'd rather have them in the top right of the 'main' screen 0.  Can I control this placement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

notify-osd is supposed to show on your primary screen, unfortunately [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/331369) is currently in the way.

It's currently targeted to be fixed as an update to natty, so unfortunately the best thing you can do right now is mark the bug as affecting you in Launchpad.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks for prompt heads-up.  I guess I should have search launchpad myself. :-/

Comment: This one is killing me.  I just went back to the radeon driver so dual display would work right, but I forgot about this bug.  Might have to turn my laptop screen off again.

Comment: @MarkRussell: check my answer below. There is a workaround that worked great for me.

Answer (score 10):

A workaround for the bug, suggested in comment #104:

- Install/Open `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to `/apps/notify-osd/multihead-mode`
- Change from the default `dont-focus-follow` to **`focus-follow`**
- Log out and back in

Notifications will now show in the same monitor as the current active window.

Comment: I didn't even need to log out. Started working right away.