# Where do I place a logout script for LightDM?

Tags: lightdm

Previously in Karmic, we created a logout script that does some work in the background on backing up a users home directory, this script was put in the `/etc/GDM/PostSession` directory.

I can't figure out where to put a script that I want to run during a logout in LightDM.

I've searched and have found many people who are looking for this answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

At least since Ubuntu 12.04 there is now an option `session-cleanup-script` which can be added to the [SeatDefaults] section of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz` is the documentation:

```
# session-cleanup-script = Script to run when quitting a user session (runs as root)
```

Do not forget `chmod +x yourscript` to give your script executing permission.

After changing a value in lightdm.conf it takes only effect after lightdm is restarted. You can either reboot or login to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and run `sudo restart lightdm`.

(Thanks to Krytarik who posted this answer in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649)

Comment: If you add a cleanup script and log out, it won't work immediately. It seems as if you have to reboot first.

Comment: You only have to restart lightdm. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but I didn't think of that and tried 15 times to log out and in again. Fortunately I didn't delete my test script and after reboot (I had given up already) it worked... :)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 this can cause side effects. session-cleanup-script is also called if the user has typed wrong username or password. I'm currently searching for another way to setup a logout script which is really called only if the user logs out.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
session-setup-script = Script to run when starting a user session (runs as root)

session-cleanup-script = Script to run when quitting a user session (runs as root)
```

in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file.

Sources:

- `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz`
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. I think you need to follow [bug in launcpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/876284)

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)