# How can a run a login/logout script as root?

Tags: login, lightdm, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place a logout script for Lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68407/where-do-i-place-a-logout-script-for-lightdm)

How can I make login/logout scripts?

Something like `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` and `/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default`.