# How can I synchronize my user settings between my desktop and my live USB?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, sync, window-manager

I've got a persistent-storage live USB (with a separate casper-rw partition), with Xubuntu 14.04 on it. I've got the same OS on my desktop, and I'd like to be able to synchronize my settings between the two, so that when I change things like panel layouts and keyboard shortcuts on one device, it gets updated on the other. That way, when I'm working on my live USB on other computers, I'll have the same familiar layout and shortcuts.

How can I do this? My hack at it would be to make a script that runs when I log out, and copies my settings files to the live USB if it's connected. I'd also like to do the same thing on the USB, so when I'm using it on my main computer, it will sync any changes I make there as well. (One would have to be lower priority to avoid conflicts; I'd make the script on the USB prompt me before syncing.)

Will this work? I'm very new to Xubuntu, and I just started dual-booting with Windows a couple months ago, so I'm not sure what files need to be copied, and which, if any, I should avoid moving.

Answer (score 0):

Apps settings are saved on hidden files in user home. Usually in ".config".

Use "la" command to see hidden files.

I will test copy ".config" and ".local" to your USB:

```
cp -Rf ~/.config ~/.local /path-to-USB/home/user
```

Maybe you will need more files.

When you finish your script, you can use udev to copy files when USB is connected:

Add a new file called: /etc/udev/rules.d/96-backupPendrives.rules and write in it:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="You pendrive vendor", ATTRS{model}=="your pendrive model", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/pathto/script"
```

Use "udevadm info -a -n sdb" to find your USB data. If "udevadm" doesn't work, change sdb by sdc or sdd,...

You can run scripts at session logout in lightdm:

[Where do I place a logout script for LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68407/where-do-i-place-a-logout-script-for-lightdm)