# Will Gwibber get Google+ support?

Tags: gwibber, google

Will Gwibber be getting Google+ support?  I would like to post statuses from my desktop at anytime like Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Google+ in Gwibber?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243981/how-do-i-use-google-in-gwibber)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google+ doesn't really have a write API yet so no one can write this feature (yet), however you can follow along progress in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/805452).

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Comment: What about read API?