# How do I use Google+ in Gwibber?

Tags: gwibber, google

I know that the Gwibber client supports Facebook and Twitter, but is it possible to use it with Google+?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google+ does not have an API for doing the things you can do with Twitter and Facebook, from something like Gwibber. Thus, there is no plug-in for Gwibber to use Google+. There is no way to authenticate with Google+ and get your circles information, and filter streams or such, via the current API.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/805452

Comment: Is there any plan to release one soon?

Comment: @nick A plug-in being released depends on Google+ making the APIs for doing such activities available to the public.