# Can I collapse the "Shortcuts" area in the Dash?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash

Is there a way to collapse the icon area of the Dash, so that I just see the search bar?

I'm pretty sure I was able to do this in 11.04. I remember having it set up so that I would only see the search bar when dash was open. I think there may have been a drop-down button to collapse it.

But I no longer see this in 11.10. Am I crazy or was this feature removed? Can I get it back? I never use the icon area at all (or the lenses for that matter) and would like to hide or disable them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression from 11.04, I hope to see it fixed in 12.04:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/849334
- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)