# How do I add TweetDeck to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, adobe-air

I managed to get TweetDeck running on 11.04. I installed a version of Adobe AIR from the archive, then just copied the contents of `/opt/TweetDeck` in from another Ubuntu 10.04 machine. Now, I'm trying to get the TweetDeck Icon in the launcher, and failing miserably. Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you looked at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/13758/18612) first to see if it answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in general with Adobe AIR applications and the Unity Launcher. See this bug report if you want to follow along:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/796558
- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Typically adobe air would create a desktop launcher when installing that you could put to use.

In this case you copied over so browse here, if there is a tweakdeckfastXXXX.desktop inside then just grab with cursor & drop on to the unity launcher.

```
/opt/TweetDeck/share/META-INF/AIR
```

You may or may not need to do a log out/in  afterwards.

Another option, if the .desktop is there, is to copy to it  ~/.local/share/applications, **then** drag & drop onto your unity launcher