# Dell Latitude E6510 black screen after last update on 11.10 Intel Graphics

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, updates, display, dell

After last Friday(20/01/2012) update, when I turned on my laptop today I got a black screen on it. It is on, I can see the back light, but it's all black only my secondary display is ok.

Screen is Ok, when I reboot I can see Dell logo a Ubuntu colored screen before login but then... black. I need to attach secondary monitor to do anything.

I saw A lot of issues with Nvidia but mine is Intel Graphics.

I was already on 11.10 just did an update.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a black screen on my laptop as well. I rebooted node and got into grub (hit shift key as Dell logo fades away).

Select revert to old kernels and pick kernel(3.0.0-14) and hit enter. Now it should work as good as it used to work before.

Answer (score 3):

The bug has been reported. You can follow the progress here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/919350

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. The only solution I found so far is to go back to the previous kernel version.
Regarding to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97888/dell-latitude-e6510-black-screen-after-last-update-on-11-10-intel-graphics) 3.2 may also work, but it's not the case on my system (DELL Latitude 5410).