# Passwords in the Password/Encryption Keys program

Tags: encryption, password, keyrings

I noticed that I have passwords in the Password/Encryption Keys program  . It appears that anybody who walked up to my computer could go look at all my passwords without needing a master password. Did I do something wrong or is this the default behavior? And if so, why?

and what if i lock my password is it get locked till i log out or for every time when i have 2to see password then i have to unlock keyrings . if then so how i protect my passwords from other . and why it is done so

Comment: i know this is bug is there any solution to hide that

Comment: This is a bug. There isn't much you can do about that.

Comment: I this is bug . i want that I lock my all keyrings and when I try to open it promt me for password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock the passwords:

1. open seahorse
2. Right click on Passwords and choose lock

Always lock your Computer when leaving the Desk!

Seahorse is the tool to manage keys and passwords:
[to the seahorse manual](https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/)

Comment: @konard thanks this is good help for me . But i want to know if i lock passwords and when i restart my computer then i have 2 lock again . and which condition its get unlocked

Comment: see this for more infos: [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=551036)

Comment: and more: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a security bug with Seahorse, the tool that manages passwords. A bug report has already been filed both in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/189774) and [GNOME bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=551036) regarding this bug. You can also read up on the [Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1302342) that was discussing this exact issue with Seahorse.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea to solve the problem quoted from the forums;

he way I see it Ubuntu is almost there, seahorse does ask permission just no confirmation. And we do have the tools like `gconf`. And `policykit`, witch can handle non-root permissions and IMO is way under used.

Here's my idea, create a sane list of default apps that can access seahorse. The ability to change that list through gconf, and permission checks through policykit for unexpected apps, changing info or viewing passwords. And finally come up with a unified personal security policy for the desktop as a whole

Comment: is this idea is helpful