# How to install the latest Octave

Tags: software-installation, octave

I want to install Octave on my Ubuntu LTS with `apt-get`. The problem is that the official repositories list only Octave 3.0 and Octave 3.2, whereas the latest Octave is Octave 3.6.

How do I update the repositories of apt-get to get Octave 3.6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will Octave 3.6.1 be available to be installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124731/when-will-octave-3-6-1-be-available-to-be-installed)

Comment: No, this is about installing it in 10.04 while your link is about 12.04-12.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you install the latest version of GNU Octave?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194151/how-do-you-install-the-latest-version-of-gnu-octave)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epicaso/+archive/octave) should solve your problem, provided you are running the latest 12.04.

Open Terminal `Ctrl-Alt-T` and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:picaso/octave
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install octave
sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

---

For Ubuntu 20.04, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/206050/124466) answer.

Comment: even after `update` the repositories are not showing octave 3.6. I am searching in both synaptic and apt-get

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: Repos in both answers are for **12**.04 LTS only :(. Can you upgrade?

Comment: will soon. Finals are in progress. after that.

Comment: but can you describe how ppa's can be restricted to ubuntu versions?

Comment: PPAs *must* usually be restricted to specific versions because they contain binaries which have been compiled on that specific version, for that specific version.

Comment: This ppa today brings us 3.6.1 version, newest available (stable) on GNUoctave site is 3.6.4

Comment: For 14.0.4.2, I had to use a bit of both answers:

    "sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:picaso/octave"
    "sudo apt-get update "
    "sudo apt-get install octave"
    "sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev"

These made octave 4.0 run, but not with --force-gui

    "sudo apt-get build-dep octave"

was also required to get --force-gui to work.
Screw this non-formatting of of comments.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is quite simple. Go to the [Octave downloads website](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/) and find the latest release of GNU Octave and download the .tar.gz file of it.

After this copy and paste the following terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mv octave-x.x.x.tar.gz ~
cd ~
tar xvf octave-x.x.x.tar.gz
cd octave-x.x.x
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Where the 'x.x.x' refers to the version of GNU Octave you'd like to install, such as 3.6.3.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 3):

Just as an update: [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mtmiller/+archive/octave) (maintained by a member of the Debian Octave Group) provides the latest Octave for a range of Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

I am only "answering" this because I could not format in the comments. kudos to @izx and @Brenton Horne

For 14.0.4.2, I had to use a bit of both answers:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:picaso/octave
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

These made octave 4.0 run, but not with `--force-gui`

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
```

was also required to get `--force-gui` to work.

Answer (score 1):

This does not use `apt-get`, but an alternative mechanism, `flatpak`, which has its own elaborate [installation instructions](https://flatpak.org/setup/), depending on Linux distribution and desktop environment used.

You can run the newest version of Octave (5.1.0 since March 2019) by running it as a Flatpak app. "Flatpak is a system for building, distributing, and running sandboxed desktop applications on Linux."

The installation procedure for the Octave package is described here: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.octave.Octave (2 commands at bottom of page)

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, You have to install flatpak first, then run Octave:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak  # optional, AFAIK
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
flatpak run org.octave.Octave --gui
```

This downloads about 1.5 GB from the internet, because it installs KDE dependencies as well.

On my machine, it installs this:

```
       ID                                            Branch        Download
 1. [|] org.kde.Sdk                                  5.12          < 825,1 MB
 2. [ ] org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs         8.08         < 4,9 MB
 3. [ ] org.kde.Sdk.Locale                            5.12         < 337,3 MB (partial)
 4. [ ] org.octave.Octave                             stable       < 117,0 MB
```

Note that Octave 5.1.0 itself is only 117 MB.

To upgrade, I had to uninstall the octave flatpak, then run flatpak install.

Answer (score -3):

Latest ppa is ppa:octave/stable.

https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable

This ppa is maitained by the "GNU Octave" team and has version 3.8.1 available for lucid and precise.