# installing octave3.4 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, octave

I try to install ocatve 3.4 under Ubuntu 10.04 to be able to work in eclipse. I followed the link [How to install the latest Octave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138832/installing-the-latest-octave-3-6-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts) I have an output:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install octave-3.4.3-64-bit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
octave-3.4.3-64-bit is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-matplotlib-data ttf-lyx python-tz python-pyparsing
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

when I try to run octave I have:

```
~$ octave
The program 'octave' can be found in the following packages:
 * octave3.0
 * octave3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I am not sure what I should do, I found there http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_GNU/Linux that 3.4.3 is the latest version for Ubuntu 10.04. I am not sure if I have to remove all packages, or set-up some path or do it in different way. 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click this http://ubuntuone.com/6iTsUm8xqX7rXDf3S6yfeM

open it with software center to install .