# How do you install the latest version of GNU Octave?

Tags: octave

Yet again I am to turn to this wonderful resource available to me and ask, how do I install the latest version of GNU Octave (not Octave 3.2.4 -- the one available in the software centre)?

Comment: It doesn't work at my system... The following lines seems to be OK wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.8.0
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
./configure
make but the last one seems not work... sudo make install The system tells me, that is not a rule defined. What's wrong with the procedure...? Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: This is what happens when i try to run using the command on terminal. ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/octave’: Permission denied

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For octave 3.6.1

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:picaso/octave
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install octave
```

Yes you can get octave-3.6.3 , open your terminal and paste this

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.6.3
./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Hope that helps :D

Comment: Well this is something I suppose, but I was hoping for something that would give me the latest version of Octave (3.6.3)

Comment: @BrentonHorne hi answer updated

Comment: That does help :)

Comment: One other thing, how do I create a launcher in Cairo-Dock for Octave 3.6.3?

Answer (score 60):

You can add the `ppa:devacom/science` PPA to install the latest version of Octave (6.4.0, as of January 2021) in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:devacom/science
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install octave
```

---

Alternatively, you can use flatpak to install the latest version of Octave in Ubuntu 18.04+.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
```

Then you can run it from the terminal with the command `flatpak run org.octave.Octave` (the GUI version is available too).

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1385349/124466) question to create a wrapper script `octave`, if you don't want to execute the long command `flatpak run org.octave.Octave` again and again.

---

*The PPA mentioned in this part of answer is inactive since 2018, and it is kept for historical purposes.*

You can install the latest stable version of GNU Octave for any supported Ubuntu release:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

This PPA is maintained and supported by several Octave developers.

Comment: @mike-miller helped me to find out that in Ubuntu we should use: `sudo -H apt-get install octave`. If not, the `.config/octave` folder will be created in the user's home folder with root ownership and Octave will not start. With `sudo -H` the `.config/octave` folder is created in the root home folder.

Comment: See Link in Octave Wiki: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Octave.27s_Personal_Package_Archive_.28PPA.29_for_Ubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately this repo has broken packages that do not provide all versions of dependencies.  octave : Depends: libcxsparse3.1.2 but it is not installable
          Depends: liboctave4 (= 4.2.1-2~octave~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqhull6 but it is not installable
          Depends: libqscintilla2-11 but it is not installable

Comment: @Martin it looks like you are trying to install octave from this repository on the wrong Ubuntu release. Check that the repository source definition matches the release you have installed.

Comment: As of Jan 2018 this ppa is still needed to install 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, which only ships 4.0.0

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu 12.04.3 and Octave 3.8.0 with statistics**

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.8.0
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
./configure
make
sudo make install

sudo apt-get install octave-statistics
octave
pkg install -forge io
pkg install -forge statistics
pkg load statistics
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally now I know you can copy the following into the terminal:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-version#.tar.gz
tar -xvf /home/username/octave-version#.tar.gz
sudo rm /home/username/octave-version#.tar.gz
cd /home/username/octave-version#
./configure
make
ln -s /home/username/octave-version#/run-octave /usr/local/bin/octave
```