# How to create a wrapper script for the Flatpak version of Octave, to avoid the long command flatpak run org.octave.Octave?

Tags: command-line, flatpak, octave

In the `apt` version of octave, I can use the command `octave script.m` to execute the file `script.m`. Similarly `flatpak run org.octave.Octave script.m` works too.

However, to avoid the long command `flatpak run org.octave.Octave`, I created a file `~.local/bin/octave` with the contents `flatpak run org.octave.Octave`, and marked it as executable (I already removed the `apt` version of Octave). While it runs octave just fine, `octave script.m` does not work anymore, it only opens the command line version of Octave.

I know that I can open Octave and run the script from within, but I am interested to know if the script can be directly run from terminal with the flatpak version of Octave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just installed [Octave 6.4.0 from Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.octave.Octave) on my Ubuntu  20.04.3 LTS system, then rebooted and I'm able to execute my `script.m` file from terminal from both MATE and GNOME as simple as:

```
flatpak run org.octave.Octave script.m
```

Or create a wrapper script by

```
cat <<'EOF' | tee ~/.local/bin/octave
#!/bin/bash
flatpak run org.octave.Octave "$@"
EOF

chmod +x ~/.local/bin/octave
```

and call Octave from Flatpak by executing `octave script.m`. Make sure that `~/.local/bin` is defined in your `$PATH` variable.

Note: make sure that you do not have both deb- and Flatpak-versions of Octave. Remove the first by `sudo apt-get autopurge octave` if you prefer Flatpak.

---

If Flatpak fails on your system, you can install Octave 6.4.0 from [some PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edevacom/+archive/ubuntu/science) by executing below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:devacom/science
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Comment: Maybe the reboot was all what was needed. I also installed it specifically for this question, got it to work while in the /home directory, but not after copying the script to another direcrtory (and cd-ing into it). Still, you may see the error `Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the trick is to unset the environmental variable `SESSION_MANAGER` [[source]](https://github.com/flathub/org.qgis.qgis/issues/62).

In order not to interfere with your regular environment, prefer to unset the environment only for the current command using `env`:

```
env -u SESSION_MANAGER flatpak run org.octave.Octave script.m
```

Of course, you can make your life much easier defining for example an alias:

```
alias octave='env -u SESSION_MANAGER flatpak run org.octave.Octave'
```

From now on, you can run an octave script as of old:

```
octave script.m
```

Include the alias definition in your `~/.bashrc` configuration file so it is always available in an interactive terminal.

Comment: @terdon thanks for correcting the error in the command for the alias definition!