# octave 4 no GUI & some features not installed

Tags: 14.04, libraries, octave

I installed octave 4 by compiling source as given in [How to install Octave 4.0.0 in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645600/how-to-install-octave-4-0-0-in-ubuntu-14-04/645718#645718)

but i am not able to use GUI.
  octave --force-gui gives me only commandline in terminal .
please guide me to get GUI & other features .(if libraries are missing please tell me how to install libraries and get the featurs)
hear is log file [config.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jfwf0JDy33M3Q0R1lXV1V0MWs/view?usp=sharing) ...
BY seeing in log file i found this list :

1. Build Octave GUI: no
2. JIT compiler for loops: no
3. Build Javainterface: yes
4. Do internal array bounds checking: no
5. Build static
       libraries: no
6. Build shared libraries: yes
7. Dynamic Linking: yes
       (dlopen)
8. Include support for GNU readline: yes
9. 64-bit array dims
       and indexing: no
10. OpenMP SMP multithreading: yes

    11. Build cross tools:                  no

---

thank you

Comment: Did you installed `qtoctave` . ?

Comment: But octave 4 has gui of its own. &I think qtoctave is dead . Qtoctave is working but I am trying for default GUI

Comment: Probably your system lacks one or more of the dependencies necessary to build the GUI, so that component was skipped. You will need to examine the `config.log` file to figure out what: if you need assistance, then [edit] your question to include the relevant section of the log file e.g. `grep -B120 -A20 'Build Octave GUI' config.log`

Comment: hello @steeldriver ,i  edited the question as you suggested  . could you help

Comment: I think I'm being stacked at almost the same step...
I found by running $ ./configure configure: WARNING: OpenGL libs (GL and GLU) not found -- disabling GUI This might be a key of solution.

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl-dev
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: -1 That doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your `config.log` shows that your system lacks the Qt development components necessary for building the octave-4.0 GUI:

```
configure:72095: checking for QT
configure:72103: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$QT_MODULES"
Package QtOpenGL was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `QtOpenGL.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'QtOpenGL' found
configure:72106: $? = 1
configure:72121: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$QT_MODULES"
Package QtOpenGL was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `QtOpenGL.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'QtOpenGL' found
configure:72124: $? = 1
No package 'QtOpenGL' found
configure:72152: result: no
configure:73317: WARNING: Qt libraries not found -- disabling GUI
```

---

You will need to install at least the Qt toolkit dependencies noted in the `INSTALL.OCTAVE` file that ships with the octave-4.0.0 source:

```
Qt
     GUI and utility libraries ().  Qt is required for building the GUI.
     It is a large framework, but the only components required are the
     GUI, core, and network modules.
```

The specific Ubuntu packages are `libqtgui4` `libqtcore4` and `libqt4-network` however unless disk space is severely limited you may wish to install the comprehensive `libqt4-dev` package instead

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

---

Although it's targeted at Debian rather than Ubuntu, you may find this additional resource helpful [Octave for Debian systems: Compiling from source - The right way](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#The_right_way).

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to not be enough to fix the problem. After installing many other packages, I've reduced the warnings to only the one about not finding OpenGL, but the steps you described didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `libqt4-dev`, `libqt4-opengl-dev` and `unixodbc-dev` packages, then it worked.