# When will Octave 4.0 be added to the software center?

Tags: software-center, octave

Octave 4.0 has been available for several months now, but the software center is still providing Octave 3.8.1.  Are there any plans to add support for 4.0 sometime soon?

Comment: See also this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/645718/110109

Answer (score 1):

It is already available, for [15.10 and 16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=octave). As for 14.04, you'll have to [request a backport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports#Requesting_a_Backport); [nobody has requested one yet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubp?field.searchtext=octave&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=).