# Netbeans all menu fonts are bold after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: fonts, netbeans

After updating ubuntu to 12.04 all fonts got bold. I haven't installed themes or configured fonts.

from netbeans about:

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828)
>
> Java: 1.7.0_03; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 22.1-b02

[image: preview]

Comment: add '--laf Nimbus' at the command. Netbeans will look a little different but the fonts will look like before. Your Command: /bin/sh "/home/whatever/netbeans-7.1.2/bin/netbeans" --laf Nimbus

Comment: Open queue voters, this question is getting a bunch of traffic, perhaps we should keep it open as it seems to be actively solving people's problems.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is a bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/669159
- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

In the first link, there is a comment that will point you to [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/937200). There you can find the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core
```

Comment: sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core solved my problems. Thank you.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core solved my problems. Thank you

Comment: Works like a charm!
I have been using netbeans 7.3 on ubuntu 12.10 then i upgraded java from 1.6 to 1.7 thats when i got this font issue. After running this command everything went back to normal

Comment: I think this issue surfaces upon installation/upgrading of WINE as `fonts-unfonts-core` was selected when upgrading WINE from the official Ubuntu repository's 1.4.* to the official WINE-development repo's 1.7.7 (with Ubuntu 13.04).

Comment: Yeah, I also recently installed WINE, after which Netbeans started to look wonky.

Comment: works fine! upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10

Comment: I like those counter intuitive solutions :), Thanks @Jorge

Comment: I found that `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` had to be removed as well

Answer (score 1):

My Netbeans was showing the IDE font as all italics after an OS upgrade.
I ran the command `sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-core` and this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution of removing fonts of course works but it's not very elegant

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core
```

instead you can simply change options in Netbeans by editing the file

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/etc/netbeans.conf
```

which you can also find with a simple

```
find / -name netbeans.conf
```

and then add the following line to netbeans options:

```
-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Metal
```

so you should get a line similar to:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Metal"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of the bug, there is also a blog post listing two other solutions to solve the problem rather than removing the the fonts:

- http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/netbeans-ide-look-feel-under-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Please edit your answer and include the main parts of the article here.