# Key short cut `Super+L` (i.e. `Win+L`) not working for `LockScreen` in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

I want to change Key short cut  to  `Super+L` for `LockScreen` but it is not working. If I try any other combination like `CTRL+ALT+L` or `CTRL+ALT+G` , it works.
`Win+L` combination used to work in 11.10.

[image]

Comment: Have same problem and it's damn annoying :/

Comment: Anybody else have `Win/Super + l` make their display settings  reverted to a previous setting? I used the System Settings to rotate my display and I noticed that pressing Win+L will flip flop it between normal rotation and the 90degree rotation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's very annoying, and hard to remember the exact fix. So hopefully this will help you, and also be an easy way for me to look this up next time I do a fresh Ubuntu install.

There is duplication & conflict between the Gnome Keyboard Shortcut settings (as depicted in your screen shot) and the same settings in the new Unity desktop. Ubuntu (well, Gnome) provides a UI for editing the Gnome Keyboard Shortcut settings but as you've learned, they don't work if they conflict with Unity. And there is no UI installed by default for managing Unity.

**Note** that to get 'Super-X' style shortcuts to work, you will have to change the 'key to show the launcher' setting, which means that the Super/Windows key will no longer open the launcher. If that's OK with you, continue...

Here is what I do:

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager (some will warn you not to, because it gives you enough power to really mess things up). There may be a way to change these without using CCSM but if so, I don't know it. Install it via the Ubuntu Software Center, or:

   `$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run CompizConfig Settings Manager; acknowledge the warning message.
3. Locate and click the `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` icon in the `Desktop` section
4. Change the `Key to show the launcher` (on the `Behaviour` tab).
   To do this:

   - Click the button which says `<Super>`
   - Click `Grab key combination`
   - Press a new key or key combination (this will, from now on, open the Unity launcher); I use `<Alt>-<Super>`

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager - changing launcher key]

The `<Super>-L` 'Lock Screen' combination that you already set up should now *just work*!

**Bonus**

Note that CCSM also provides its own facility for setting keyboard shortcuts. For things not included in the gnome-control-center, you may have more luck defining custom shortcuts in CCSM. If you select `Commands` from the `General` section in CCSM, you can define custom commands, like I've done here:
[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager - Commands editor]

...and then, you can associate those commands with specific key combinations, like this:
[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager - Key bindings]

As you can see, I've configured Super-E to launch the Gnome text editor, and Super-C to launch the calculator. I find both of these very handy.

Comment: NB: The screenshots are a little different for 13.10 but this method still works. Note that `/usr/bin/gcalctool` doesn't exist in 13.10; it's `/usr/bin/gnome-calculator`

Comment: Looks like 14.04 has Super-L preconfigured to lock the screen, among other more convenient shortcuts. However, I still had to install CCSM and reconfigure what's now called the "Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay", in order to configure Super-T for anything besides the hard-coded but rather useless (to me) Trash browser.

Comment: Looks like unity-tweak tool will do the trick; no need to install ccsm. `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` and then run it. Under Unity->Additional, and change the 'Show the Launcher' setting.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [confirmed bug #951805](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/951805) in Ubuntu since 12.04 beta 1 stage. Unfortunately no solution is available as of yet, but everyone being affected by this bug can sign in to Launchpad and subscribe to the bug report for future updates.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu and none of the solutions worked for you, then you may consider resetting to default settings.

You wont lose anything except reverting your settings to defaults,

```
$ dconf reset -f /
```

Note that this may also reset application that use dconf to save settings.