# HUD keeps popping up when watching movie in movie player

Tags: totem, hud

When I watch a movie in Movie Player, the HUD pops up every 8 minutes or so.  I am not touching the keyboard or the mouse at all.  Alt makes the bar go away, and then 7-8 minutes later, it pops up again.  This happens when I'm watching fullscreen or not fullscreen.

Can you help me fix this?  I've been using VLC instead (because it does not have this problem), but I don't like it as much as Movie Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totem has a unique feature that it activates Alt every 30 seconds to prevent the screen from going black. But since HUD is triggered by Alt key as well, you see the HUD popping up as you watch the movie.

Possible things you can do to resolve this:

- Use another media player other than Totem. But since you don't like VLC, we shall neglect this option.
- [Disable HUD or change the key that triggers HUD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key).
- Or upgrade Totem's version to 3.5 or later as [this "bug" has been fixed in that version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/921276/comments/19). But, I wouldn't recommend that option.

A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/921276) has already been filed regarding this.

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Comment: I can make do with VLC.  I'm pretty used to using Alt for the HUD in other programs, so I don't want to change that.  What a weird bug!  Thanks.  (I didn't realize Movie Player was also called Totem; that's why I didn't find much Googling for this problem).