# Clean nodes after destroy-environment?

Tags: juju

is there possible to deploy services and after that somehow clean nodes(delete services installed before) For example I deploy wordpress and even I destroy envirement after that on node is nginx started everytime, even is something else.

And now when I deploy again wordpress another istance of nginx is installed so this is conflict.

Is there posibble to clean node after destroy-environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately we don't yet have a way for juju to clean up a node after you destroy-service.

This is a bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/932269
- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

My personal workaround is just to launch a new instance.