# What do "i2c_hid_get_input" errors mean?

Tags: dmesg

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. When I run `dmesg` in the Terminal, there are some red results and maybe bad ones. Also, there are a lot of red `i2c_hid_get_input` errors. They happen every minute, even after the boot has been finished. The format is something like this (which {time} is the time of occurrence of the error):

```
 [      {time}] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0501:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

1. What are those error and why are they happening?
2. Should I ignore them?
3. How to fix them (if they are important)?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe hid refers to a human interface device (touchpad perhaps?)

Comment: this seems to be a common issue with touchpads on Asus laptops.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield This was happened with my Acer laptop. It would be rather touchpad-specific. However, I'm not on Ubuntu anymore. I use Fedora (with the same hardware), I just checked my `dmesg` output, and I don't see this kind of errors, not a single time. So maybe the error is fixed with recent versions of Ubuntu also?

Answer (score 2):

This problem was reported as a bug [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784152) If you are affected by this bug you should [subscribe to it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)
FWIW I don't get this on my 18.04 system with kernel 4.15.0-39 generic.