# totem v.3.26.0 fails to create gallery

Tags: 18.04, totem

Attempts to create a gallery fail silently.

I noticed that attempts to take a screenshot result in an error saying this should not happen, please file a bug report but I'm not certain the 2 issues are connected.

I found something in the forums that indicated that removing gstreamer1.0-vaapi would resolve the problem but that approach resulted in no change whatsoever in behavior so I re-installed it.

`totem-video-thumbnailer inputvideo outputpng` will happily create a single screenshot.

I had the same issue with several assorted resolutions of H265 encoded Matroska files and also a 1280x720 H264 MP4. (the only non H265 footage I had available)

I tested totem 3.18.1 under Ubuntu 16.04 and it does not appear to have the create gallery issue as that works fine on both of the files I tested it on (the aforementioned 1280x720 H264 MP4 as well as an 885x480 H265 file. (It fails to take a screenshot (silently) but the gallery creation is my main concern)

In a terminal on launch totem 3.26.0 says

```
(totem:13101): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:42:33.598: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node slider owner GtkScale)
```

Attempting to create a gallery results in:

```
Gtk-Message: 19:46:56.986: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

regardless of which of the aforementioned versions I use so I think that the   Gtk-Message can safely be ignored.

`apt list --installed |grep libgstreamer` results in

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

reinstalling totem had no effect.

If there's any more useful information I can provide, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems do not appear to be connected other than they are both bugs.

If you are affected by the create gallery problem I suggest that you [subscribe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) to this [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1798399)

If you are affected by the take screenshot problem I suggest that you [subscribe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) to this [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1800840)

Update:

It appears that the gallery option will be [removed from the documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/issues/268) for totem-video-thumbnailer and the [gallery code has been split in a different binary](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/commit/a642fd971)

Update 2: An upgraded package has been [accepted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1798399/comments/14) into cosmic (18.10) proposed. as well as [bionic proposed.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1798399/comments/25) It should make it's way into updates soon.